# Run another command regardless of the success of protractor test

Tags: node.js, angular, protractor

**Purpose:**
I want to always run another node script no matter whether protractor tests are all passed or not. To make it easier, I used the following command:

```
protractor tests/protractor-config.js ; npm run uitest
```

**Problem:**
The output of the command above will be:

```
$ iris.web.portal@1.0.0 e2e E:\IRIS\IRIS\Iris.Cloud\Iris.Web.Portal
$ protractor tests/protractor-config.js ";" "npm" "run" "uitests"
Usage: protractor [configFile] [options]
configFile defaults to protractor.conf.js
The [options] object will override values from the config file.
See the reference config for a full list of options.
```

**Understanding:**
I think protractor CLI didn't handle semicolon properly.
When I try

```
protractor tests/protractor-config.js && npm run uitest
```

It works as expected.

**My config**
I was using protractor@5.3.2.

Have anyone met the problem before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason `protractor tests/protractor-config.js ; npm run uitest` failed  was because protractor took `;` `npm` `run` `uitest` as options to the command protractor.

The reason second one worked for you is because the tests passed; The `&&` is the AND operator , so my conjecture is if your tests fail `npm run ui tests` will not run . because `false && <anything else>` will result in false & would not get evaulated.

Example : `ls <non-existent directory && echo2` will result in `ls: <non_existent directory name>: No such file or directory`.

Hence if you want to run a task irrespective of whether `protractor tests/protractor-config.js` passes or not , you might want to have a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts.

Spefically : npm test, pretest & posttest

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what I still don't understand is why '&& npm run uitests' won't be taken as options to the command protractor like it does with '; npm run uitests'?

Comment: @YanXu The AND Operator (&&)  is an logical operator . Hence the above said behaviour.  For its said behaviour you might wanna look at the docs.